# Rails javascript_include_tag wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Trying to simply add my manifest application.js file to my main layout, but each time it's throwing me this argument error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

</head>
<body>
```

And the error:

wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Should note that application.js is correctly in the app/assets/javascripts directory.

EDITED TO INCLUDE FULL ERROR TRACE

```css
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:208:in `process_require_directive'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:167:in `block in process_directives'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `each'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `process_directives'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:99:in `evaluate'
tilt (1.4.1) lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/environment.rb:75:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:295:in `[]'
sprockets-rails (2.2.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:230:in `lookup_asset_for_path'
sprockets-rails (2.2.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:190:in `check_errors_for'
sprockets-rails (2.2.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:137:in `block in javascript_include_tag'
sprockets-rails (2.2.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:136:in `map'
sprockets-rails (2.2.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:136:in `javascript_include_tag'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___4159364249305868628_70237323168960'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/oren/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
app/controllers/layouts_controller.rb:4:in `index'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.1.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (1.0.7) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (1.0.7) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:87:in `start'
thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/runner.rb:200:in `run_command'
thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/runner.rb:156:in `run!'
thin (1.6.3) bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/oren/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
/Users/oren/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
/Users/oren/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/oren/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

and here is my application.js file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll   appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README    (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require lib/angular.min
//= require lib/angular-route.min
//= require instagroups
//= require tree .
```

Even if I include another argument, I still get this same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?

Comment: Rails 4.2 and i'm still typing because SO makes me

Comment: Is that the whole file?  If so, I guess you should close off our `html` and `body` tags.  Where are you yielding your views?

Comment: No, not the whole file haha. I'm using Angular for my views and a controller called Layouts to render my template.

Comment: Worth including the whole error trace as it might highlight the location of the problem (I don't think it's the javascript_include_tag itself).

Comment: Edited to include full trace

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it could be related to carriage returns on the end of lines in your javascript. There's an issue in the [cataput gem](https://github.com/maccman/catapult/issues/6) that looks very similar. The suggestion is to convert the application.js file to have line feed (\n) line endings (unix format).

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Often your text editor will be able to do it (for example on SublimeText I can do View => Line Endings => Unix). Failing that most OSes have a dos2unix utility that you can install.

Comment: Damnit, I was quite hopeful of that! Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just need `require_tree .` rather than `require tree .` in your `application.js`. (Note underscore instead of space).

Comment: Oooh! A new error!

SyntaxError: [stdin]:10:26: missing )

:(

Comment: The hunt for the `missing )` might be another problem (and question altogether.

Comment: Would it be in the compiled JS? If so, that wouldn't be so hard.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I missed that the error was a javascript error rather than a further error in the asset preparation.

Comment: So, then, I should go diggin' through my code? That sounds fine.

Comment: I removed everything from application.js but it's still not working (giving the same error).